# Applying a XSLT transformation to an ASPX file

Tags: asp.net, parsing, xslt

We're about to restructure a large project of several hundred ASPX pages performing significant changes. I was planning on using XSLT to strip/edit the pages however the two tools I've tried are unable to Parse ASPX due to the server declarations in the pages.

The tools I've used in the past are [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) and [xsltproc](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html)

test.cmd

```
REM xml tr  --html test.xsl %ProjDir%\%%f > %%~dpnf.ascx
libxslt\xsltproc.exe --novalid --html -o %ProjDir%\%%~nf.ascx test.xsl %ProjDir%\%%f
```

test.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
    <xsl:output 
        method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" 
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
        <!-- method="html" text xml disable-output-escaping="yes"  -->

    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output;

```
test//Test.aspx:1: HTML parser error : htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="Test.aspx.vb" 
 ^
test//AcronymAdd.aspx:21: HTML parser error : Tag fc1:frontendheadercontrol invalid
<fc1:FrontEndHeaderControl ID="Heading" runat="server" />
                                                       ^
...
```

Can anyone recommend a method for parsing asp.net pages to enable application of XSLT templates too them?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do a simple search-and-replace on the aspx files before running them through your XML tools (which seem like reasonable tools to me, FWIW; I've done lots of web data extraction with them). It seems like the only problem with the aspx files are the <% %> directives, which you could either ignore transform into XML elements:

Approach 1: turn aspx directives into comments:

sed 's/<%/<--/g; s/%>/-->/g'

Approach 2: turn aspx directives into xml (won't work if @Page is left implicit):

sed 's/<%@ *//>/g'

The other error message comes from not having an XML Namespace declaration. You can just add them; the URL they point to doesn't need to be real.

Answer (score 0):

Store it as XML in the database instead and pull the content into a specified section of the page and apply to XSLT to it there? A major port, and if you going to go to that trouble you might as well go the whole mile and store it as HTML5. You could then create your own page layouts to pull the content into, basically a CMS. In the latter case, you could totally avoid XSLT and use CSS which is far more appropriate for crafting a modern front end UI.